# Poor results in audio denoising

Tags: audio, deep-learning, keras

My first try with Keras is not really a success.

The aim is to try audio denoising with DNN.

**Datas used, features/label & pre-processing**

Input files came from CHIME3 Contest (clear file = *.CH0.wav, noisy files = *.CH[1-6].wav, CH2 is very noisy) => sampling freq = 16k

Training set uses STFT (Nfft=1024, overlap=512, hamming symmetric of size 1024).
Each sample :

input feature is composed with 5 FFTs (FFT[n-4] FFT[n-2] FFT[n] FFT[n+2] FFT[n+4]). Step = 2 because of overlapping, so each FFT represents different temporal datas ==> size=5*153

Label if clear FFT[n] ==> size=513

Over all the training set, i normalize by the max of all STFT points. I don't normalize each frequency bin separately!

**Model**

```
OUTPUT_SIZE = 513
N = 5

def myDNN():
    INPUT_SIZE = N*OUTPUT_SIZE
    N_HIDDEN = 3
    HIDDEN_SIZE = N*OUTPUT_SIZE
    OPTIMIZER = Adam()

    INPUT_KERNEL_INITIALIZER = 'glorot_uniform'
    HIDDEN_KERNEL_INITIALIZER = 'glorot_uniform'

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(HIDDEN_SIZE, input_shape=(INPUT_SIZE,),     activation='relu', kernel_initializer=INPUT_KERNEL_INITIALIZER))
    for _ in np.arange(1,N_HIDDEN):
        model.add(Dense(HIDDEN_SIZE, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=HIDDEN_KERNEL_INITIALIZER))
    model.add(Dense(OUTPUT_SIZE, activation=OUTPUT_ACTIVATION, kernel_initializer=HIDDEN_KERNEL_INITIALIZER))
    model.summary()

    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=OPTIMIZER, metrics=['mae', 'mape'])

    return model
# end of "myDNN"
```

**Training results**

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #  
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 2565)              6581790  
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 2565)              6581790  
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 2565)              6581790  
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 513)               1316358  
=================================================================
Total params: 21,061,728
Trainable params: 21,061,728
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________

Window (Type=hamming / SubType=symmetric / M=1024 / R=512) is COLA: unity_factor(1.080000) distanceMax(0.000000)
Train on 677 samples, validate on 291 samples
```

Epoch 1/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 7.2885e-04 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0127 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 161.7868 - val_loss: 6.6317e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0121 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 123.4798
Epoch 2/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 5.6384e-04 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0112 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 121.1596 - val_loss: 5.9110e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0114 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 120.3071
Epoch 3/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 4.7981e-04 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0107 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 122.1414 - val_loss: 5.3739e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0111 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 121.2984
Epoch 4/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 4.1580e-04 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0103 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 119.0018 - val_loss: 5.0105e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0109 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 118.8770
Epoch 5/100
677/677 [==============================] - 3s 4ms/step - loss: 3.5760e-04 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 115.1305 - val_loss: 4.6629e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0108 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 118.4515
Epoch 6/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 3.0869e-04 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0095 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 110.9568 - val_loss: 4.4396e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0107 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 117.2114
Epoch 7/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 2.6181e-04 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0090 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 109.0506 - val_loss: 4.2265e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0106 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 116.6763
Epoch 8/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 2.2784e-04 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0087 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 105.7562 - val_loss: 4.1528e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0106 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 116.5105
Epoch 9/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 2.0152e-04 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0083 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 103.1178 - val_loss: 4.0624e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0104 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 116.0003
Epoch 10/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.7865e-04 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0079 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 101.4013 - val_loss: 3.9868e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0105 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 118.7820
Epoch 11/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 1.5592e-04 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0076 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 98.5259 - val_loss: 3.8894e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0103 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 114.0532
Epoch 12/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.3583e-04 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0072 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 96.4760 - val_loss: 3.8807e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0103 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 116.4706
Epoch 13/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.2042e-04 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0069 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 94.3490 - val_loss: 3.8566e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0102 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 115.7845
Epoch 14/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.0864e-04 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0067 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 92.4231 - val_loss: 3.8057e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0102 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 116.7057
Epoch 15/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 9.7562e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0064 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 90.5527 - val_loss: 3.7299e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0101 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 113.3712
Epoch 16/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 8.6729e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0061 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 88.2068 - val_loss: 3.7412e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0102 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 117.1941
Epoch 17/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 7.7495e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0059 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 86.4357 - val_loss: 3.7269e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0101 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 115.7683
Epoch 18/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 7.0167e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0056 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 84.3882 - val_loss: 3.7583e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0101 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 115.8617
Epoch 19/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 6.4919e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0054 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 82.7943 - val_loss: 3.7276e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0102 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 116.1259
Epoch 20/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 5.8948e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0052 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 81.2488 - val_loss: 3.7231e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0101 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 118.1728
Epoch 21/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 5.3392e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0050 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 79.3921 - val_loss: 3.7716e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0102 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 117.6861
Epoch 22/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 5.0231e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0049 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 78.1898 - val_loss: 3.7441e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0101 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 115.7151
Epoch 23/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 4.6693e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0047 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 76.6721 - val_loss: 3.7050e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0101 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 116.1317
Epoch 24/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 4.3750e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0045 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 75.3499 - val_loss: 3.7227e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0101 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 116.3584
Epoch 25/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 4.1647e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0044 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 74.2149 - val_loss: 3.7047e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0101 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 115.7465
Epoch 26/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 3.9346e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0043 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 72.9056 - val_loss: 3.7119e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0101 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 115.7475
Epoch 27/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 3.7841e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0042 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 71.9992 - val_loss: 3.7553e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0101 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 116.5080
Epoch 28/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 3.6194e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0041 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 70.8470 - val_loss: 3.6943e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0101 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 116.5066
Epoch 29/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 3.4750e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0040 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 70.1190 - val_loss: 3.7034e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0101 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 116.0104
Epoch 30/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 3.2534e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0039 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 68.7867 - val_loss: 3.7153e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0101 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 116.9624
Epoch 31/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 3.1987e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0038 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 67.8477 - val_loss: 3.7302e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0102 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 120.9623
Epoch 32/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 3.3293e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0039 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 67.7346 - val_loss: 3.7536e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0102 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 120.4248
Epoch 33/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 3.4490e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0039 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 68.0149 - val_loss: 3.6965e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 117.3170
Epoch 34/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 3.1875e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0038 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 67.0567 - val_loss: 3.6949e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 115.7549
Epoch 35/100
677/677 [==============================] - 3s 4ms/step - loss: 3.0422e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0037 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 66.2323 - val_loss: 3.7725e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 117.7353
Epoch 36/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 2.8864e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0036 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 65.7103 - val_loss: 3.7256e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 118.1804
Epoch 37/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 2.7293e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0035 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 64.6088 - val_loss: 3.7224e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0101 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 118.0151
Epoch 38/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 2.6166e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0034 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 63.8083 - val_loss: 3.7105e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 117.8928
Epoch 39/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 2.4192e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0033 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 62.7800 - val_loss: 3.6841e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 116.3326
Epoch 40/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 2.3085e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0032 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 61.6421 - val_loss: 3.6918e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 117.4563
Epoch 41/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 2.1701e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0031 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 60.6266 - val_loss: 3.6974e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 116.9184
Epoch 42/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 2.1066e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0030 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 59.7108 - val_loss: 3.6682e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 118.4704
Epoch 43/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 2.0509e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0029 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 58.9087 - val_loss: 3.6989e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 118.4606
Epoch 44/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.9852e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0029 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 58.2607 - val_loss: 3.6806e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 119.1714
Epoch 45/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.9317e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0028 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 57.7079 - val_loss: 3.6860e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 118.9338
Epoch 46/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.8855e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0027 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 56.8995 - val_loss: 3.6974e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 118.0525
Epoch 47/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.8299e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0027 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 56.0018 - val_loss: 3.6855e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 119.6616
Epoch 48/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.7817e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0026 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 55.3156 - val_loss: 3.6800e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 118.0859
Epoch 49/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.7699e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0026 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 54.8139 - val_loss: 3.6748e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 118.6320
Epoch 50/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.7672e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0026 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 54.6050 - val_loss: 3.6893e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 118.2951
Epoch 51/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.7555e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0026 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 54.3160 - val_loss: 3.6677e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 118.7873
Epoch 52/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.8390e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0026 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 54.5906 - val_loss: 3.7421e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0102 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 122.7614
Epoch 53/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 2.2907e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0030 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 57.1845 - val_loss: 3.6999e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0101 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 120.0913
Epoch 54/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 2.4980e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0032 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 59.5983 - val_loss: 3.6937e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0101 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 120.7630
Epoch 55/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 2.4200e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0032 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 59.6735 - val_loss: 3.7034e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 118.8989
Epoch 56/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 2.3686e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0032 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 59.4175 - val_loss: 3.7177e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 117.7602
Epoch 57/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 2.1863e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0031 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 58.5819 - val_loss: 3.7451e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 116.7871
Epoch 58/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 2.1782e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0031 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 58.2930 - val_loss: 3.7052e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 117.1842
Epoch 59/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 2.0084e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0029 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 57.0126 - val_loss: 3.6880e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 117.6743
Epoch 60/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.9072e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0028 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 56.1310 - val_loss: 3.7112e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 117.9328
Epoch 61/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.8008e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0027 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 55.2785 - val_loss: 3.6934e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 120.0999
Epoch 62/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.7170e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0026 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 54.4759 - val_loss: 3.6750e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 119.6225
Epoch 63/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.6601e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0026 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 53.8980 - val_loss: 3.6672e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 119.4439
Epoch 64/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.5888e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0025 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 53.1601 - val_loss: 3.6735e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 120.6926
Epoch 65/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.5325e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0024 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 52.4894 - val_loss: 3.6870e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 117.3724
Epoch 66/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 1.5193e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0024 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 52.2543 - val_loss: 3.6746e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 117.4701
Epoch 67/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.4864e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0024 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 51.5119 - val_loss: 3.6769e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 119.4155
Epoch 68/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.4551e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0023 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 51.0115 - val_loss: 3.7009e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 120.2584
Epoch 69/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.4419e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0023 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 50.8094 - val_loss: 3.6882e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 119.0246
Epoch 70/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.4328e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0023 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 50.5945 - val_loss: 3.6890e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 118.0751
Epoch 71/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.4189e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0023 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 50.5335 - val_loss: 3.6800e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 119.6180
Epoch 72/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.4037e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0023 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 50.2688 - val_loss: 3.6724e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 117.7447
Epoch 73/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.3913e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0023 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 50.1438 - val_loss: 3.6685e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 118.6204
Epoch 74/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.3639e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0022 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 49.7017 - val_loss: 3.6834e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 119.2991
Epoch 75/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.3579e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0022 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 49.4682 - val_loss: 3.6681e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 119.6100
Epoch 76/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.4235e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0023 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 49.6413 - val_loss: 3.6695e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 122.1114
Epoch 77/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.5278e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0024 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 50.7402 - val_loss: 3.6557e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 120.1452
Epoch 78/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.4826e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0024 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 50.7138 - val_loss: 3.6674e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 120.0096
Epoch 79/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.4832e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0024 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 50.8613 - val_loss: 3.6930e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 120.3776
Epoch 80/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.4744e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0024 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 50.7794 - val_loss: 3.6842e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 118.6103
Epoch 81/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.4683e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0024 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 50.8070 - val_loss: 3.6689e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0100 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 122.0331
Epoch 82/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.4900e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0024 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 50.9410 - val_loss: 3.6562e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 120.1546
Epoch 83/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 1.5309e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0025 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 51.2366 - val_loss: 3.6825e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 118.3575
Epoch 84/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.5005e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0024 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 51.3449 - val_loss: 3.6631e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 119.6261
Epoch 85/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.4770e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0024 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 51.0710 - val_loss: 3.6769e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 118.6728
Epoch 86/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.4455e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0024 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 50.8061 - val_loss: 3.6757e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 119.7171
Epoch 87/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 1.4352e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0024 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 50.4469 - val_loss: 3.6544e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 120.0981
Epoch 88/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.3743e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0023 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 49.9120 - val_loss: 3.6824e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 119.5353
Epoch 89/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 1.3597e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0023 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 49.3628 - val_loss: 3.6652e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 119.6446
Epoch 90/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 1.3599e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0023 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 49.3746 - val_loss: 3.6628e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 120.9546
Epoch 91/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.3597e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0022 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 49.1547 - val_loss: 3.6580e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 119.0343
Epoch 92/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.3619e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0023 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 49.0541 - val_loss: 3.6591e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 120.1974
Epoch 93/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.3998e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0023 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 49.1881 - val_loss: 3.6623e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 120.8473
Epoch 94/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.3483e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0022 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 49.0619 - val_loss: 3.6726e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 121.5829
Epoch 95/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.3479e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0022 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 48.9206 - val_loss: 3.6646e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 121.1559
Epoch 96/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.3106e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0022 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 48.5896 - val_loss: 3.6615e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 119.1754
Epoch 97/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.2860e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0021 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 48.1067 - val_loss: 3.6683e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 119.8193
Epoch 98/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.2812e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0021 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 47.8122 - val_loss: 3.6745e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 118.7239
Epoch 99/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.3072e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0022 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 48.0826 - val_loss: 3.6792e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 120.3317
Epoch 100/100
677/677 [==============================] - 2s 3ms/step - loss: 1.2905e-05 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0021 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 47.6981 - val_loss: 3.6494e-04 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0099 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 118.2943

**One result after iSTFT** [From top to bottom: Noisy input / Clear reference / DNN output]

If I only look temporal representation, it seems not so bad BUT if I look spectrogram ...
[Temporal Representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gA0KZ.png)
[Spectrogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HalsR.jpg)

Anyone can help me, please?
Ideas? Upgrades?
Enormous error from dummy?

Comment: Well.... it seems that there is a clear barrier perventing high numbers. Is the `OUTPUT_ACTIVATION` suited to the range of the true output?

Comment: If you listen to the output, does it sound good?

Comment: Perhaps something could be done with the loss that you use. MSE has a very flat slope when it has small values like in your case and that makes training slow and difficult. Perhaps you could try to use mean_absolute_percentage_error as loss and add MSE to metrics so that you can compare to previous results.

Comment: Daniel, I forgot the line about OUTPUT_ACTIVATION. It's "reLu". Labels are normalized over all the training set by its max, so I think it's coherent. About listening, it 's not good, it sounds like a robot voice!

Comment: Manngo, thank you, I'll try that

Comment: Manngo, It's worth. I just change loss function from 'mse' to 'mape'. Now, mse is x40, mape is stuck to "677/677 [==============================] - 5s 7ms/step - loss: 99.9993 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0053 - mean_squared_error: 4.0830e-04 - val_loss: 99.9994 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0048 - val_mean_squared_error: 3.4798e-04". And output predicted is strictly equal to 0!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I assume you are trying to predict the magnitude of the complex coefficients you obtain from the fft, right? 
The picture of the predictions you posted doesn't look that bad. I observe that the main problem lies in the predictions of the high frequencies. This is a very common issue in processing audio signals with neural networks.  Possibe solutions/ideas:

- Take the logarithm of the magnitudes in both your inputs and your targets. Then the natural high energy difference between the lower and the higher frequencies is somehow equalized.
- Furthermore, try to apply an emphasis weighting in your loss function. More emphasis to the higher frequency bins leads to a faster learning in that region. In keras it is quite easy to define a custom loss function ([How to create custom objective function in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33859864/how-to-create-custom-objective-function-in-keras))
- Checkout residual neural networks. The applied skip connections can be extremly useful in your task. The layers can learn to only estimate the noisy part of your signal which can be subtracted later on. https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8361/8badf5f7b0a5819d08ab97b5b3573fd75fae.pdf

Comment: BGraf, thank you for all these informations. I'll work on it!

Comment: I have some questions about your ideas. First point: magnitudes are, of course, strictly positive but logarithms (20*log10(X)) are not. In fact, they are almost negative. Since I chose "reLu" as activation function, it may be a problem.

Comment: Second point: indeed, it seems easy to define a custom loss function but I don't really understand what means "emphasis weighting". Input parameters of loss function are Ytrue and Ypred, so high frequencies (for my problem) are the second half-part of each Y. Loss = mean((Ytrue "1st half" - Ypred "1st half")**2) + 5*mean((Ytrue "2nd half" - Ypred "2nd half")**2) is "emphasis weighting"?

Comment: Regarding your first question: Assuming your magnitudes are in a range from ]0,1]  then you will get only negative values from the logarithm. A common practice would be to rescale those values again to the interval [0,1]. You will wend up with the same value range but in a logarithmic scale.

Comment: Your second question: Yes that would be some form of emphasis weighting. In your example you put 5 times more weight to the higher frequencies and consequently emhasize them. However, the exact formulation of your loss function needs to be investigated.